# Pass message from Controller to AJAX script in View

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using jQuery and AJAX in the View to send some data to the Controller that writes it to the database. On success I show a div tag with a green background with "OK" text. But what if I do a check first in the Controller if the data already exist in the database, then I would like to alert the user that the data could not be added. Is there a way to pass some kind of message back to the AJAX script?

I guess the success option is just a confirm of contact with the Controller and not a real confirm that everything is OK and the data has been added to the database!?

What action in the Controller would cause the error function in the AJAX code to run?

Finally I just wonder what kind of return I should use since I'm actually not returning anything?

My script in the View:

```
        $.ajax({
        url: "/Orders/AddOrder",
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: { a: order, b: seller },
        success: function () {
            console.log('AJAX successful');

        // Show confirm message
            $(".messageOk").show();
            $(".messageOk").text("OK").delay(2000).queue(function () {
                location.reload();
            });
        },
        error: function () {
        ????
        },
        complete: function () {
        ????
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
        // Add new Resource
    public ActionResult AddOrder(int a, int b)
    {
        var order = new Order
        {
            OrderNumber = a,
            Seller = b
        };

        db.Orders.Add(order);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //return new EmptyResult();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); // ??????
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return the appropriate HTTP status code from your controller action: `409 Conflict`.

```
if (the resource already exists in db) {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
}
```

which will trigger the `error` AJAX function in which you could check whether you are in this situation and act accordingly:

```
error: function(jqXHR) {
    if (jqXHR.status == 409) {
        alert('Sorry but this resource already exists');
    }
}
```

As you can see this way it's up to the view to decide what error messages to display based on proper HTTP status codes returned from the server. This way you are not cluttering the server with view logic.

Comment: In cases where a 500 can be due to multiple reasons, we might need some message from the server to point out the error. Now its up to the guy consuming the API to whether render the same message or use a default one for all 500s. 
you might have seen this error code and error message being returned with lot of the REST APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can I also use some HTTP status code to trigger the complete function? Or is the Success function a real confirm that task i done or just a something that triggers when AJAX has established contact?

Comment: The complete function is triggered after the `success` or `error` functions are called.

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla, 500 status code means an unhandled server side error has occurred. This case should always be handled by the client the same way: by displaying an `oops, something went wrong page`. For other reasons there are respective status codes that can be used in the HTTP protocol specification. So as long as you write a really RESTful API on the server you shouldn't be worried to much. All that the client must do is act accordingly based on the proper status code returned from the server as shown in my example with the 409 code.

Comment: OK, but what really triggers the success? Does any HTTP status code return something in the background? Does success means data has been written to the database or just established contact with the Controller?

Comment: The `success` function is triggered by a success server side HTTP response code. This means `>= 200` and `< 400`. In your case `success` should mean that the data has been successfully written to the database. Since a new resource is created you might consider returning the more appropriate [`201 Created`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.2) HTTP status code accompanied with the corresponding `Location` response header pointing to the URI where the newly created resource can be retrieved.

Comment: So basically all you need to do is read the HTTP protocol specification and write a corresponding RESTful API based on it. You will see how there's already all you need in this specification to cover all the possible cases.

Comment: OK, the thing about 201 Created and Location response header pointing to URI, is this instead of the reload I do with the page with javascript. When I reload the page I can see that the add item really are there. But what about the common return in the end of the Controller!? Does this has any role in this case, sice there isn't any Model to send to the View!?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with the reloading. It's to point the client to where the newly created resource resides if it decides to fetch it with an additional AJAX call. In your case returning a new Partial View in the success case might just work fine. This partial view could then contain only the partial markup that you would inject into your DOM in the `success` callback in order to update the grid or wherever you are displaying your resources.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the correct response status code, you can also pass in your response body error messages from the server may be as JSON string or plain string

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A short code example would be nice to understand how you mean!?